# How to add actions to multiple JButtons en JTextfields with inner ActionListener classes?

Tags: java, class, actionlistener

Hi I have a problem with the functionality of my JButtons and JTextfields.
I want to add multiple buttons and text fields to one JComponent(=panel) but I can't seem
to get any result when activating them. The print methods are not executed. 
I have linked each button via an inner class to it's (print)method. The adding of 
each text field and button and defining of each of these elements as Action Listeners happens
in separate methods, namely activateButton & activateTextfield.

Can anyone see what is wrong ? Any help or suggestions is very much appreciated !

btw the error is probably not syntax based, everything compiled, just had some problems putting the code on the forum.

```
Import bla bla (everything is imported :)
public class Gui { every JButton, every JTextfield is defined as a field, panels and frame to


/**
 */
public Gui()
{
    makeFrame();
}

protected JComponent makeTextPanel(String text1, String text2) {
    String nieuwelijn = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    /**JPanel*/ panel = new JPanel(false);
    JLabel filler = new JLabel( "<html> + owyeah" + text1 + "<br>text2<br>text1<br>text2<br>text1</html>"); 
    filler.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);
    filler.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.TOP);
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
    panel.add(filler);

    return panel;}



 // define each created textfield as actionlistener and add it to the given panel
private void tekstveldActiveren(JTextField t , JComponent p)
{
      t.addActionListener(new Afhandelaar2());
      p.add(t);
}
// define each created textfield as actionlistener and add it to the given panel
private void knopActiveren(JButton k , JComponent p)
{
      k.addActionListener(new Afhandelaar1());
      p.add(k);
}


private void makeFrame()
{
    frame = new JFrame("Interface");
    frame.setSize(600, 300);

    JPanel contentPane = (JPanel)frame.getContentPane();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(12, 12, 12, 12));
    makeMenuBar(frame);

    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(6, 6));

     JPanel centerPane = new JPanel();
      {
        centerPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(8, 8));

        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();

        JComponent panel1 = makeTextPanel("5","kamer 1");
        tabbedPane.addTab("kamer 1",panel1);

        JButton tabknop1 = new JButton("knop1");
        JButton tabknop2 = new JButton("knop1");
        JButton tabknop3 = new JButton("knop1");
        knopActiveren(tabknop1, panel1);
        knopActiveren(tabknop2, panel1);
        knopActiveren(tabknop3, panel1);

        JTextField tekstveld1 = new JTextField("0",5);
        JTextField tekstveld2 = new JTextField("0",5);
        JTextField tekstveld3 = new JTextField("0",5);
        tekstveldActiveren(tekstveld1 , panel1);
        tekstveldActiveren(tekstveld2 , panel1);
        tekstveldActiveren(tekstveld3 , panel1);

        JComponent panel2 = makeTextPanel("kamer 1","kamer 1");
        tabbedPane.addTab("kamer 2",panel2);

        JButton tabknop4 = new JButton("knop1");
        JButton tabknop5 = new JButton("knop1");
        JButton tabknop6 = new JButton("knop1");
        knopActiveren(tabknop4, panel2);
        knopActiveren(tabknop5, panel2);
        knopActiveren(tabknop6, panel2);

        JTextField tekstveld4 = new JTextField("0",5);
        JTextField tekstveld5 = new JTextField("0",5);
        JTextField tekstveld6 = new JTextField("0",5);
        tekstveldActiveren(tekstveld4 , panel2);
        tekstveldActiveren(tekstveld5 , panel2);
        tekstveldActiveren(tekstveld6 , panel2);

         JComponent panel3 = makeTextPanel("kamer 1","kamer 1");
         tabbedPane.addTab("kamer 3",panel3);

         JButton tabknop7 = new JButton("knop1");
         JButton tabknop8 = new JButton("knop1");
         JButton tabknop9 = new JButton("knop1");
         knopActiveren(tabknop7, panel3);
         knopActiveren(tabknop8, panel3);
         knopActiveren(tabknop9, panel3);

         JTextField tekstveld7 = new JTextField("0",5);
         JTextField tekstveld8 = new JTextField("0",5);
         JTextField tekstveld9 = new JTextField("0",5);
         tekstveldActiveren(tekstveld7 , panel3);
         tekstveldActiveren(tekstveld8 , panel3);
         tekstveldActiveren(tekstveld9 , panel3);

         centerPane.add(tabbedPane);

    }
    contentPane.add(centerPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    Dimension d = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    frame.setLocation(d.width/2 - frame.getWidth()/2, d.height/2 - frame.getHeight()/2);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

}

    private class Afhandelaar1 implements ActionListener {     
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent g){   
        if(g.getSource()== tabknop1){System.out.println("tabknop 1");}
        else if(g.getSource()== tabknop2){System.out.println("tabknop 2");}
        else if(g.getSource()== tabknop3){System.out.println("tabknop 3");}
        else if(g.getSource()== tabknop4){System.out.println("tabknop 4");}
        else if(g.getSource()== tabknop5){System.out.println("tabknop 5");}
        else if(g.getSource()== tabknop6){System.out.println("tabknop 6");}
        else if(g.getSource()== tabknop7){System.out.println("tabknop 7");}
        else if(g.getSource()== tabknop8){System.out.println("tabknop 8");}
        else if(g.getSource()== tabknop9){System.out.println("tabknop 9");}
    }
   }

  private class Afhandelaar2 implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent h)
     {
      if(h.getSource()== tekstveld1) {System.out.println(conversieMethode(tekstveld1));}
      else if(h.getSource()== tekstveld2){System.out.println(conversieMethode(tekstveld2));}
      else if(h.getSource()== tekstveld3){System.out.println(conversieMethode(tekstveld3));}
      else if(h.getSource()== tekstveld4){System.out.println(conversieMethode(tekstveld4));}
      else if(h.getSource()== tekstveld5){System.out.println(conversieMethode(tekstveld5));}
      else if(h.getSource()== tekstveld6){System.out.println(conversieMethode(tekstveld6));}
      else if(h.getSource()== tekstveld7){System.out.println(conversieMethode(tekstveld7));}
      else if(h.getSource()== tekstveld8){System.out.println(conversieMethode(tekstveld8));}
      else if(h.getSource()== tekstveld9){System.out.println(conversieMethode(tekstveld9));}

    }

  }


}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Also, source using English attribute & method names would be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

You should cast the result of the actionlistener.getSource method, and then compare to the other components based on your attributes. For example, if in your panel, every jTextField has **unique** text, you can do something like this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent h){
     if (((JTextField) h.getSource()).getText().equals(tekstveld1.getText())){  
           System.out.println(conversieMethode(tekstveld1));
     }
     ...
}
```

Of course you can compare based on other attributes beside text.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks, but the idea is that every field could contain a value that does not have to be unique, they are actually just simple input fields for each time one integer value.

Comment: You could use the .hashCode() function which returns and int unique to each object.